# TimeDistributed Layer how to define input_shape when TimeDistributed received: (None, 1)

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer

**Challenge**

How to define TimeDistributed Layer input_shape when TimeDistributed received: (None, 1). What is the reading to receive (None, 1)?

**Basic Code**

```
n_features = 1
n_seq = 2
n_steps = 2
X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], n_seq, n_steps, n_features))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv1D(64, 1, activation='relu'), input_shape=(n_seq, n_steps, n_features)))
```

**Input Shape Error**

```
--> 175           '`TimeDistributed` Layer should be passed an `input_shape ` '
    176           f'with at least 3 dimensions, received: {input_shape}')
    177     # Don't enforce the batch or time dimension.

ValueError: `TimeDistributed` Layer should be passed an `input_shape ` with at least 3 dimensions, received: (None, 1)
```

**Imports**

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv1D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling1D
```

**Code Ref**
This code is from an online sample code on RNN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved in shape using this definition, there was batch for shape on input shape param:

```
input_shape=(None, n_steps, n_features))
```